# Comparing two columns one of which is null

Tags: oracle

I have three tables as follow

```
TABLE1
ID           VALUE
1             NULL
```

---

```
TABLE2
ID           VALUE
1                1
```

---

```
TABLE3
ID           VALUE
1               10
```

I'm trying to do the following:

Compare the two fields (ID) in tables 1 & 2 if one is null return null then return value from TABLE3.

Comment: Huh?  Not clear.  Please show expected output sample for each scenario, and read [ask].

Comment: definitely not clear but maybe you are looking for nvl2?  as in nvl2(table1.id, table2.id, table3.id)  so if table 1 id is not null show table 2 id if it is null show table 3 id

Answer (score 0):

It seems you are looking for something like this:

```
select table3.id, table3.value
from table1 join table2 on table1.id = table2.id
            join table3 on table1.id = table3.id
where table1.value is null or table2.value is null
```

If this isn't what you had in mind, you need to give more details about your requirement.

Answer (score 0):

Try this query:

```
SELECT t1.id,
       (CASE WHEN t1.value IS NULL OR t2.value IS NULL 
             THEN t3.value
       END) VALUE
  FROM table_1 t1
  JOIN table_2 t2
    ON t1.id = t2.id
  JOIN table_3 t3
    ON t1.id = t3.id
```